# Rails: Combine multiple tables search conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

```
def self.search(search)
  Post.where("caption LIKE ?", "%#{search}%") 
  Post.joins(:tags).where('tags.name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%" )
end
```

Here, I'm trying to combine both the conditions with an OR statement i.e. I want to be able to search through both post captions and tag names. How would I join them in a single line? Thanks!

**PostsController**

```
def index
  if params[:search]
    @posts = Post.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
  else
    @posts = Post.all.recent.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

**post.rb**

```
has_many :taggings
has_many :tags, through: :taggings
```

**tag.rb**

```
has_many :taggings
has_many :posts, through: :taggings
```

**tagging.rb**

```
belongs_to :post
belongs_to :tag
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to join two tables and write the search conditions. Make sure to use LEFT JOIN, because JOIN will never give you a post that has no any tag. 
So, don't do it like this:

```
# This produces an SQL query with JOIN (not LEFT JOIN).
# Posts without tags will never be found.
Post.joins(:tags).where(...)
```

Instead, use `Post.includes(:tags)` whith `references` clause:

```
# you have to use 'references' clause here to produce a normal LEFT JOIN query instead of eager loading associations
Post.includes(:tags).where("posts.caption LIKE :search OR tags.name LIKE :search", search: "%#{search}%" ).references(:tags)
```

Or you can write the query condition manually using `joins`:

```
Post.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN taggings ON taggings.post_id = posts.id LEFT OUTER JOIN tags ON taggings.tag_id = tags.id')
.where("posts.caption LIKE :search OR tags.name LIKE :search", search: "%#{search}%").uniq
```

If you are using Rails 5, there is a new method `left_outer_joins` that will do the same:

```
Post.left_outer_joins(:tags).where("posts.caption LIKE :search OR tags.name LIKE :search", search: "%#{search}%")
```

Comment: I tried the one with `joins` and it worked like a charm (although I had to change `.order("created_at DESC")` to `.order("posts.created_at DESC")` in `PostsController` as I was getting an "ambiguous column" error). Thanks!

Comment: Could you please update the line with `joins` for models with has_many :through association? I've updated my post with extracts from the models

Comment: Edited the manually written join condition. The rest should be fine.

Comment: Hmm had to do a little tinkering to get it to work. At first it wasn't returning posts without any tags, but then I changed it to `Post.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN taggings ON taggings.post_id = posts.id LEFT OUTER JOIN tags ON taggings.tag_id = tags.id').where("posts.caption LIKE :search OR tags.name LIKE :search", search: "%#{search}%").uniq` and now it works perfectly. I was also badly looking for `.uniq`, and now that I've learned about it, it helped me solve another sql related problem I had in another model! Thanks!

Comment: You are right. It was my mistake. Edited the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
Post.joins(:tags).where("posts.caption LIKE :search OR tags.name LIKE :search", search: "%#{search}%" )
```

Comment: I tried something similar with `Post.joins(:tags).where('posts.caption || tags.name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%" )`. Neither works. It seems to be searching only through the tag names

Comment: Yes I did. It has the same result as the one I mentioned i.e. it searches only through the tag names

Comment: You might want to change LIKE with ILIKE if its case sensetive issue

Comment: If you are using LIKE 'Text' will not match '%text%'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Post.joins(:tags).where("caption LIKE ? OR tags.name LIKE ?", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")
```

Answer (score 0):

For advanced filtering, I'd use scopes. You could create two scopes with the queries and call them both in the controller.

Model:

```
scope :search1, -> (search) {where("caption LIKE :search", "%#{search}%")}
scope :search2, -> (search) {joins(:tags).where('tags.name LIKE :search', "%#{search}%" )}
```

Controller:

```
@posts = Post.where(nil)
@posts = @posts.search1(params[:search]) if params[:search].present?
@posts = @posts.search2(params[:search]) if params[:search].present?
@posts = @posts.recent.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
```

More about scopes here: http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/search-and-filter-rails-models-without-bloating-your-controller/

His post helped me a lot, I recommend you to read it :)